# Python 3: Why does .append() work in the scenario instead of the second?

Tags: python, list, syntax

I'm learning Python 3 through Codecademy and am struggling to understand the difference between these bits of code:

```
def append_size(lst):
  lst.append(len(lst))
  return lst
```

vs

```
def append_size(lst):
  return lst.append(len(lst))
```

Both functions are called with `print(append_size([23, 42, 108])`

Why does the first work (prints [23, 42, 108, 3]) and the second returns 'None'?

Comment: The return value from `.append()` is `None` which is what is returned in the second version of the function.

Comment: It works, it will even change the list in the outer scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the `append` function is used to add an item to an existing list.

Suppose I have a list `a = [1,2,3]` and I want to add `4` to the list. I'll do `a.append(4)` and would get the desired output of `[1,2,3,4]`.

In the first `append_size` function the code firstly appends an item to the original list and then returns the list that's why you get a list output of `[23, 42, 108, 3]`. But in the second function the code returns `lst.append` and not any list. Because the `append` function always has the value None, it returned None as the output.

Comment: Okay wicked, this makes a lot more sense for me now, thank you so much for the help :) I spent a long time being confused about `.append()`, but I guess I didn't realise `.append()` has no inherent value and I was calling `.append()` rather than the updated list

Comment: @Elfayylmao I like how you use "wicked" as an expression. And good luck coding!

Answer (score 2):

This happens because when you `append()` something to a list nothing is returned. It simply appends the item to the list and returns `None` if you print it. Eg:

```
l = [1,2,3]
print(l.append(4))
None
```

In this case, `4` is getting appended to a list called `l`. The simple task of append is adding the item to the list at the end. Hence, when you do `print(l.append(4))` it says `None`.

But if you try:

```
l = [1,2,3]
l.append(4)
print(l)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Here it prints the **value** of the list `l` after `4` is appended.